# Referencing a Location in an Array rather than the Data within it. (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, pointers, reference

I'm writing a project that requires me to use a graph traversal algorithm over a grid-like structure made up of `Unit`s. I'm creating the grid so that each unit of the grid has references to the each of its neighbors:

```
class Unit {
    boolean type, visited;
    Unit up, left, down, right;
    Unit(Unit u, Unit l, Unit d, Unit r) {
        up = u;
        left = l;
        down = d;
        right = r;
    }
}
```

I create a grid of `Unit`s by adding a new `Unit` object to each position with the neighbors in the form of references to other locations in the grid:

```
Unit[][] grid = new Unit[height][width];

for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
        grid[i][j] = new Unit(
            i == 0 ? null : grid[i - 1][j],
            j == 0 ? null : grid[i][j - 1],
            i == height - 1 ? null : grid[i + 1][j],
            j == width  - 1 ? null : grid[i][j + 1]
        );
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, whenever some of the grid `Unit`s are created, their neighbors are `null` so they do not hold the correct reference. To solve this I just run this entire algorithm over again so that it has every grid element filled, but this seems like a very inefficient and ugly solution.

What I would like to do is hold the `Unit` object as a "dynamic" index of the grid so if a certain position gets updated then the neighbor reference in the appropriate `Unit`s would also get updated. This acts as a sort of promise by the grid saying that if a position `(i, j)` becomes filled then the neighboring `Unit`s will have the updated information.

---

Thank you to anyone who can help me solve this!

P.S. I realize that I can store the indexes to the grid in the `Unit` class for the neighbors but that would restrict me to the specific grid I have in this example and it would make it necessary to make the call to get the item everytime it is updated. I may not want to store it in a two-dimensional array like I do it here, so I want a generalizable system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating your very first `Unit` using your constructor, there are no adjacent units, so your references are going to refer to null. You could instead check if an adjacent cell contains a null reference (being mindful of the adjacent cells i and j values), and if so, create a `new Unit()`.

Comment: But when I create those `new Unit()`s they will also have no neighbors yet instantiated. Also there would be checks for almost every `Unit` because most of them will not have been created yet by the definition of the problem.

Comment: You are correct that there will be checks for every unit. That is essentially what you are asking though isn't it? Basically, you want to say, if a neighbouring cell already has a unit assigned, then use that reference in my constructor, otherwise create a new instance of Unit. So I'd suggest adjusting the call to your constructor to perform those checks and instantiate objects where necessary